# NameError: name 'master' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I got this Error all the time and i dont understand what could be wrong. 
Im not that experienced in programming so i need ur help.
If u help me the Flying Spaghetti Monster will protect u for a at least a month.

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

            self.master = master
            self.frame = Frame(self.master)
            self.frame.place(x=self.rx(), y=self.ry())
            self.button = Button(self.frame, text="Quit", fg="red", command=self.destroy)
            self.button.pack(side = LEFT)

    def destroy(self):
            self.__init__(self, master)
            self.frame.destroy()
```

After running i got the error message:

```
line 23, in destroy
    self.__init__(self, master)
NameError: name 'master' is not defined
```

Comment: Why do you call `__init__` in `destroy`?

Comment: I want to call the function again

Comment: OK, but that makes no sense here...

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order for others to be able to help you, please provide more context. Thanks.

Comment: My programm should close the button and also create a new one if u click on the button. The next button should do the same. Because of that i wanted to call the "main function" again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
def destroy(self, master): # <----- Corrected.
        self.__init__(self, master)
        self.frame.destroy()
```

I think you should do it this way:

```
def destroy(self):
        self.frame.destroy()
```

After you initiated the `Class`, and before you call the `App.destroy()`, the class already has `self.frame` object. No need to re-define the `__init__`.